# How do i create only ONE rewrite line in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have similar friendly url's like this:

```
http://localhost/galeria
http://localhost/galeria/
http://localhost/galeria/cat
http://localhost/galeria/cat/
```

I want to rewrite **ONE** rule in my htaccess file. So far, i was able to create 2 rules, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^galeria/?$ gallery/newest.php [L]
RewriteRule ^galeria/cat/?$ gallery/newest.php [L]
```

How do i create only ONE rewrite line for my 4 fiendly url's?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this single rule:

```
RewriteRule ^galeria(/cat)?/?$ gallery/newest.php [L,NC]
```

`(/cat)?` makes `/cat` optional thus matching all 4 URLs

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eD9qS4/1)